# Laravel inserting multiple data from table html to database

Tags: html, mysql, database, laravel, controller

[How can I save multiple data from the html table to the database by just one saving?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl8xZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to insert multiple rows at once is using `Model::insert($data)`. To use this method, you should prepare data first. Here's correct data structure for `insert()` method:

```
$data = [
    ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 32],
    ['name' => 'Steve', 'age' => 25],
    ['name' => 'Mari', 'age' => 20],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$insert = array(
    0 => array(
        'col1' => 'val1',
        'col2' => 'val2',
    )
    1 => array(
        'col1' => 'val1',
        'col2' => 'val2',
    )
);

DB::table('tablename')->insert($insert);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use 'name' tag for the inputs then request them in the store method of the controller like this:

```
$request->name_of_the_inputs
```

this will return to you a collection, so you should exploit the data through a for loop